# Error using mex -setup: "No supported compiler or SDK was found"

Tags: matlab, mex, matconvnet

I am using MatConvNet with the Microsoft Visual C/C++ 2015 compiler. It was installed and it worked. However, when I run `mex -setup` I get the error message `No supported compiler or SDK was found.` MatConvNet still works and the compiler file is clearly in `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\bin\win64\mexopts` so why do I get that error message?

Answer (score 2):

Call:

```
  mex -v -setup
```

Then look in the details, why your compiler was not found.

In my case e.g. it was because the registry variable:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7

was set to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestPro

instead of

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using MATLAB R2017b. [The list of supported compilers](https://nl.mathworks.com/support/compilers.html) states that R2017b supports MS Visual C++ 2015 **professional**, so I'm guessing, you're using the **community** edition.

In that case, the easiest way forward is to get your hands on Visual C++ 2017, making sure that MatConvNet also works there.

Comment: Thanks, @Rody Oldenhuis. Just to be clear, MatConvNet installed and compiled perfectly fine a few days ago and mex -setup showed that Visual C++ 2015 was the selected compiler. I'm just curious because now it says that there is no compiler found, when I didn't change anything on my computer.

Comment: @jlhw computers are deterministic, *something* must have changed. We unfortunately have no access to your machine, so its going to be hard to help.